# I have a question about Transformer's Q, K, V

Tags: transformer, softmax

I think the cosine similarity of negative values has its own meaning.

If you softmax the cosine similarity of Q and K, wouldn't it prevent Transformer from using information with the opposite meaning?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that before the attention block, you apply a (trainable) linear projection, and that there are many attention heads.

[image]

This gives the needed degrees of freedom to handle the potential logic of negative cosine similarity that you think the model is lacking. For instance, one head might learn to rotate the query while another one might learn not to rotate it.

Comment: If we make good use of the cosine similarity of negative values, can't we get the information that we can get from two heads from one head?

Comment: Maybe, but that would be a different model. You can experiment with that approach.

Comment: Please, consider accepting the answer (with the tick ✓ next to it).

Comment: In fact, I posted it on Stack Overflow for the first time. I appreciate you for replying. @noe

Comment: At relu activation, cosine similarities with values below a certain value are likely to be treated the same @noe

Comment: As far as I know, the only ReLU in the Transformer model is in the position-wise feedforward networks, not in the attention blocks. What makes you mention it in this context?